# Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Does Not Include Certificate with Release Build

Tags: flash, air, installation, code-signing, digital-signature

For "Project->Export Release Build" on Flash Builder 4.7, I am using (what I believe to be) a valid .PK12 keychain file, based on a Code Signing cert that I purchased from GlobalSign. I reexported the purchased key with the Root and Intermediate Keys for a valid keychain.  Flash Builder accepts this .PK12 file and builds a working Native Installer on OSX and Windows.  The Installers work on the local systems.

However, these installers have no Digital Signatures associated with them. On Windows, if I right click for Properties on any other valid downloaded installer, I can see this tab. On my built installers, there is no tab.

If I download the installers I built from a website, I get a variety of warnings of "untrusted publishers" and the installation process is difficult and painful. I cannot put my users through this.

Any ideas why Flash Builder is failing to properly sign my installers?